# how to read that kind of files in windows using python which filename has?

Tags: python, python-2.7

how to read that kind of files in windows using python, which filename has (?/\'"")

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 

'C:\\Users\\Cost2Action\\Desktop\\Myntra\\Myntra_v3.25.0_apkpure.com\\\\smali\\com\\\\appsflyer\\AppsFlyerLib$?.smali'
```

Comment: In Windows a filename cannot contain any of these characters.

Comment: more precisely, it cannot contain `?` in your example

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions - you may be interested in the list  of the reserved characters.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to open such files on Windows. I know that Windows can _see_ those files (i.e. they're displayed in the file explorer), but _opening_ them is another matter...

Answer (score 0):

for me it is working Perfectly

```
>>> f = open('pp.txt', 'rb')
>>>
```

try to write it like me
and i am on windows

Comment: If filename contains "?" then how we will opened?

Comment: the file who i opened contain a lot of URLS , and it work Fine

Comment: there are many mode , 'rb' , 'wb' , 'r',  'a' , you can use it